# Husky not getting triggered on git events

Tags: node.js, git, npm, husky, git-husky

I have created a react app which implements husky to capture lint errors:

### Environment

`git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)`, `node v8.16.2`, `npm v6.4.1`

### Lint implementation

- Created a react using `npx create-react-app my-app-name`
- Implemented eslint using `eslint --init`
- Added the script to the `package.json` file:

  `“scripts”: {“lint”: “eslint src/**/*.js”,}`
- On running `eslint src/**/*.js` or `npm run lint` the lint errors are captured perfectly

### Husky implementation

- Installed husky `npm install husky --save-dev`
- Added the husky hook to `package.json`:

  `"husky": {
      "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "npm run lint:fix",
        "pre-push": "npm run lint"
      }
    }`

### Testing git commits

- Ran `git commit -m "test commit"`

### Problem

The lint is never called when the commit is triggered. What is wrong here? Btw, I have tried solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/326).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

husky requires node > v10. Otherwise, it will skip with a warning message in the console.

Your node version is v8.16.2, please upgrade the same.